# Any reason to use older ISO C++ Language Standard?

Tags: c++

As I learn C++ in [en.cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/)
I see notes such as "C++11", "C++14", "C++17", and "C++20".

In visual studios, I can set which C++ Language standard I want to use but
is there any reason to use the older versions?
Is it to support older devices or something?

Comment: It's to support **older code**. No reason to use an older version in new code however (excepting if you find bugs in the newer implementation).

Comment: Also there are older compilers that haven't implemented the newest features yet.

Comment: If you are developing new code from scratch, probably not a lot of need.   However, if you are contributing to maintaining older code, then it may be appropriate to use older versions.    If you care at all about portability, you may need to allow for the potential of your code being built with compilers that do not comply with recent standards - for example, because the only compilers that target some platforms of interest are older compilers.

Comment: Think of all the poor suckers around the world still forced to use Turbo C++. When COVID is over and you can go to a bar, have a drink in gratitude if you are not among their number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few reasons that you might want to use an older version.

1. You may find that your old code doesn't compile with the newer versions. Fixing that security bug you just found may be a higher priority than porting a million lines of code to a new standard.
2. Your customer may specify a version to use. Maybe they don't want to upgrade their compilers just yet. Or, you might distribute your software as source and not want to limit your code to users who have the latest compiler (this is common for open source projects).
3. You might need to port your code to a crusty embedded device that doesn't have modern compilers.
4. Not all programmers are professional programmers. If C++11 is what you learnt back in the day you may be able to knock out a prototype in C++11 in less time that it would take you to learn about the new features.